# filter() by inner text returns empty parent nodes

Tags: jquery

I need to find all elements on the page which match some inner text:

```
$("body *:visible").filter( function(){ return $(this).text() == 'jQuery' } );
```

However I get parent nodes whith mathed elements in some cases. 

E.g. 

1st match: <li><a href="#">Jquery</a></li>
2nd match: <a href="#">Jquery</a>

How can I remove all the elements with parent nodes from the selection and leave only the elements which really contain defined inner text?

For the test you can try to execute the script above on [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Rather than linking to the jQuery page for some unknown reason, create a test on jsfiddle.net that demonstrates your issue.  Also, your sample case likely isn't even accurate as comparisons are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This code will iterate over text nodes of that element only and then make the comparison.

```
$("body *:visible").filter(function() {

    var childNodes = this.childNodes,
        text = '';

    $.each(childNodes, function(i, node) {
        if (node.nodeType != 3) {
            return true;
        }
        text += node.data;
    });

    return text == 'jQuery';

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ErpCG/).

Also, if you want to do a case insensitive search, be sure to use `toLowerCase()` on the text nodes before the comparison to the lowercase version of your string to match.

Comment: I believe this logic would fail on a case such as this: `<div>jQuery<b>More content</b></div>` as you're only comparing the firstChild node type.  http://jsfiddle.net/YJfbv/  The OP would seem to only want to return nodes that contain only the word "jQuery" and nothing else.  That's just my guess though!

Comment: @AdamTerlson: Sounds like you are looking at an early version of my code :)

Comment: I was indeed.  Good edit.  However, shouldn't you just `return false` instead of true when the nodeType isn't of type text?

Comment: @AdamTerlson: the `return true` is just to make the `each()` skip that iteration.

Comment: Right, but once you encounter something that isn't a text node, you already know that your element contains more than just a textNode, so you may as well break out of your loop by returning false and further return false for your filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is failing because you're comparing `.text()` values.  This will strip off all HTML markup, including that of children nodes.  If you want elements that contain no child elements and match that text, simply modify to:

```
 $("body *:visible").filter( function(){ return $(this).html().toLowerCase() == 'jquery'  });
```

Now that having been said, this is a pretty evil filter that I'd suspect is rather slow.

Comment: Thank you all. The question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

That's because [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the inner text of the element, which includes the inner text of all its descendants.

You'll have to use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) in order to only match the immediate children elements and text nodes:

```
$("body *:visible").filter(function() {
    var textNodes = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
    return (textNodes.length > 0 && textNodes[0].nodeValue == "jQuery");
});
```

Comment: This looks good, however, won't it only make the comparison to the first text node?

Comment: @alex, indeed, it only bothers to check the first text node. That's because the questioner only wants to match the elements whose *full* inner text is equal to `jQuery`. In this situation, no whitespace text nodes would exist and the value would be stored in a single text node.

Comment: Frédéric, thank you. Your solutions works perfectly but it took about 1-2 seconds to find the element. Is there any chance to improve performance of this approach (I need it to include in my Selenium 2 (WebDriver) project and performance of the test is very important for me)?